# Why do HTTP PUT requests not work after a few requests?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-httpclient, angular-http

I'm working on my premier league app, where you can create your teams, add scores to matches that ended, and see updated team data in the table, where teams sort accordingly to the [Premier League rules](https://www.premierleague.com/premier-league-explained).

**Problem:**

I have a problem with updating teams after each match. When I click to update certain match, updates match data, and then home and away teams data. But, when I start updating my matches very fast ( setting score on the website ), http put request which has to update my teams stop working. However, If I update each match slowly, everything works as it should.

So my question is, why does HTTP PUT requests, which have to update my teams, does not work, when I update matches fast ?

I am using [Local JSON Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) to store my data.
[Link to the project](https://github.com/mxnvkv/Angular-Premier-League)

**match-item.component.ts**

```js
export class MatchItemComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private premierLeagueService: PremierLeagueService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.premierLeagueService
            .getAllTeams()
            .subscribe((data: Team[]) => {
                this.teams = data;

                this.homeTeam = this.teams.filter((team: Team) => team.id === this.match.homeTeamID)[0];
                this.awayTeam = this.teams.filter((team: Team) => team.id === this.match.awayTeamID)[0];
            });
    }

    @Input()
    match: Match;

    @Input()
    matchday: Matchday;

    @Input()
    teamIndex: number;

    @Input()
    teamAmount: number;

    @Output()
    editedMatchday: EventEmitter<Matchday> = new EventEmitter<Matchday>();

    teams: Team[];
    homeTeam: Team;
    awayTeam: Team;
    settingScore: boolean = false;
    submittedScore: Match = {...this.match};


    setHomeScore(score: number) {
        this.submittedScore.homeTeamScore = score;
    }

    setAwayScore(score: number) {
        this.submittedScore.awayTeamScore = score;
    }

    setScore() {
        if (this.submittedScore.homeTeamScore && this.submittedScore.awayTeamScore) {
            this.match = { ...this.match, ...this.submittedScore };

            this.updateTeams();

            this.matchday.matches = this.matchday.matches.map((el: Match) => {
                if (el.id === this.match.id) {
                    el = Object.assign({}, el, this.match);
                }

                return el;
            })

            this.editedMatchday.emit(this.matchday);
        }
    }

    toggleSettingScore() {
        this.settingScore = !this.settingScore;
    }

    updateTeams() {
        this.homeTeam.gamesPlayed++;
        this.awayTeam.gamesPlayed++;

        // result

        if (this.match.homeTeamScore > this.match.awayTeamScore) {

            this.homeTeam.gamesWon++;
            this.awayTeam.gamesLost++;

            this.homeTeam.points += 3;

        } else if (this.match.homeTeamScore === this.match.awayTeamScore) {

            this.homeTeam.gamesDrawn++;
            this.awayTeam.gamesDrawn++;

            this.homeTeam.points++;
            this.awayTeam.points++;

        } else {

            this.homeTeam.gamesLost++;
            this.awayTeam.gamesWon++;

            this.awayTeam.points += 3;

        }

        // goals

        this.homeTeam.goalsScored += +this.match.homeTeamScore;
        this.homeTeam.goalsConceded += +this.match.awayTeamScore;

        this.awayTeam.goalsScored += +this.match.awayTeamScore;
        this.awayTeam.goalsConceded += +this.match.homeTeamScore;

        this.premierLeagueService
            .editTeam(this.homeTeam)
            .subscribe((data: Team) => {
                this.teams = this.teams.map((team: Team) => {
                    if (team.id === this.homeTeam.id) {
                        team = Object.assign({}, team, this.homeTeam);
                    }
                    return team;
                })
            })

        this.premierLeagueService
            .editTeam(this.awayTeam)
            .subscribe((data: Team) => {
                this.teams = this.teams.map((team: Team) => {
                    if (team.id === this.awayTeam.id) {
                        team = Object.assign({}, team, this.awayTeam);
                    }
                    return team;
                })
            })
    }
}
```

**league-matches.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PremierLeagueService } from '../../premier-league.service';
import { Matchday } from '../../models/matchday.interface';
import { Match } from '../../models/match.interface';
import { Team } from '../../models/team.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'league-matches',
    styleUrls: ['league-matches.component.scss'],
    template: `
        <div
            class="matchday"
            *ngFor="let matchday of matches; let i = index">

            <h2>Matchday {{ i + 1 }}</h2>

            <match-item
                *ngFor="let match of matchday.matches; let i = index; let c = count"
                [match]="match"
                [matchday]="matchday"
                [teamIndex]="i"
                [teamAmount]="c"
                (editedMatchday)="editMatchday($event)">
            </match-item>
        </div>
    `
})

export class LeagueMatchesComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private premierLeagueService: PremierLeagueService) {}

    matches: Matchday[];
    currentMatchday: Matchday;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.premierLeagueService
            .getAllMatchdays()
            .subscribe((data: Matchday[]) => this.matches = data);
    }

    editMatchday(matchday: Matchday) {
        this.premierLeagueService
            .editMatchday(matchday)
            .subscribe((data: Matchday) => {
                this.matches = this.matches.map((el: Matchday) => {
                    if (el.id === matchday.id) {
                        el = Object.assign({}, el, matchday);
                    }

                    return el;
                })
            })
    }
}
```

**premier-league.service.ts**

```js
getAllTeams(): Observable<Team[]> {
    return this.http
        .get(TEAMS_API)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
}

editTeam(team: Team): Observable<Team> {
    return this.http
        .put(`${TEAMS_API}/${team.id}`, team)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
}

getAllMatchdays(): Observable<Matchday[]> {
    return this.http
        .get(MATCHES_API)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
}

editMatchday(matchday: Matchday): Observable<Matchday> {
    return this.http
        .put(`${MATCHES_API}/${matchday.id}`, matchday)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
}
```

**interfaces**

```js
export interface Team {
    name: string,
    club: Club,
    gamesPlayed: number,
    gamesWon: number,
    gamesDrawn: number,
    gamesLost: number,
    goalsScored: number,
    goalsConceded: number,
    points: number,
    id: number
}

export interface Match {
    homeTeamID: number,
    awayTeamID: number,
    venue: string,
    city: string,
    homeTeamScore?: number,
    awayTeamScore?: number,
    id: number
}

export interface Matchday {
    id: number,
    matches: Match[]
}

export interface Club {
    clubName: string,
    logoURL: string,
    venue: string,
    city: string
}
```

Comment: [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479313/why-do-http-put-requests-not-work-after-a-few-requests)

Comment: @R.Richards , my question was edited, but because it was closed, I couldn't accept the answers, so I've created a new one

Answer (score 0):

When you use a HTTP PUT request, you end up supplying the entire object as the body of the request which will end up completely replacing the existing resource with the new one. Try using a HTTP PATCH request, which will update only the desired fields and not the entire object.

Comment: So you suggest to changer PUT to PATCH only? Or I should change something in subscribe() method as well?

Comment: Try out with PATCH, I don’t see any other changes.

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work. Maybe it is related to the other matches? Like, if I update n match, and immediately n+1, and the previous request did't complete it disappears, and so on with the next matches?